# Android How to set title in superclass

Tags: android, inheritance, titlebar

I've a group of `activities` that all extend a `baseActivity`.

I'm trying to set the `title in the BaseActivity` so it's reflected in all the sub Activites.

The app is logging in a user. I'm trying to have the `username across the title` in every screen once they have logged in.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

    public class NfcBaseActivity extends Activity{

        private static final String TAG = NfcBaseActivity.class.getSimpleName(); 
        String carername;

        public String getCarername() {
            return carername;
        }

        public void setCarername(String carername) {
            this.carername = carername;
            Log.e(TAG, "setting carername to " + this.carername);
            setTitle(carername + " is currently logged in");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //setTitle(getCarername() + " is logged in");
        }

    }   

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.entryscreen); 
            nfcscannerapplication = (NfcScannerApplication) getApplication();
            //loginWebservice = new LoginWebservice(this);
            loginWebservice = nfcscannerapplication.loginWebservice;
            userName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
            passwordPin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

            login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonlogin);
            login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    ////////////get user's input///////////


                     compId = "100";
                    String theUsername = userName.getText().toString();
                    thePassword = passwordPin.getText().toString();
                    String loginType = "1";



                    String[] params = new String[]{compId, theUsername, thePassword, loginType};

                    //validate user Asynchonously on background thread

                    AsyncValidateCarer avc = new AsyncValidateCarer();
                    avc.execute(params);
                EntryActivity.this.setCarername(fullName);

                }// end of onclick
            });
```

I call `AsyncTask` which validates a user against webservice and then sets a instance variable fullName to the user's name.

This AsyncTask is called from the Activity's `onClick()`. I use the following to call the activity's super class method `setcarer()`, which sets the title in the superclass.

I hoped this change would be reflected in all the other classes that extend the superclass.

why is this not being reflected?

```
EntryActivity.this.setCarername(fullName);
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @hazard i've tried quite a few things but none seem to work. I've put logging statements in the baseActivity class and the values are indeed being set. The title is not being set in the subclasses throughout the app

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your `fullName` variable is still null at the point of calling `EntryActivity.this.setCarername(fullName);`.

I assume you set this variable somewhere in your AsyncTask so you have to call `EntryActivity.this.setCarername(fullName);` in the `onPostExecute` method of your AsyncTask because `avc.execute(params);` continues without waiting for the AsyncTask to finish.

Comment: I've put the setCarer() inside the postExecute now. In postExecute i send an intent to the next activity. So AsyncTask has finished by then and the username is still not reflected in the next activity(which extends the baseActivity)